# Single weight definition and freezing in Conv2d

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autograd

I am dealing with a Conv2d(3,3,kernel_size=5, stride=1) and I'd need to set some specific weights to zero and render them non updatable.
For example, if I do something like

```
model = nn.Conv2d(3,3,kernel_size=5, stride=1)

model.weight.requires_grad = False
```

everything works but it affects the whole layer. I'd want to do something like this instead:

```
model = nn.Conv2d(3,3,kernel_size=5, stride=1)

model.weight[0,2].requires_grad = False  # this line does not work
model.weight[0,2] = 0                    # this line does not work either
```

it just does not seem to support assignment and requires_grad manipulation for layer parameter subgroups. Has anyone already tackled this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zero out this filter channel by either accessing the `data` attribute

```
>>> model.weight.data[0, 2] = 0
```

or using the `torch.no_grad` context manager:

```
>>> with torch.no_grad():
...     model.weight[0, 2] = 0
```

As you noticed you can't have `requires_grad`s specifically set for submodules. As such all parameter elements of a given module share the same flag, they either get updated or they don't.

One alternative way would be to kill the gradient of that channel manually just *after* the backward pass has been called, just *before* the optimizer step:

```
>>> model(torch.rand(2, 3, 100, 100)).mean().backward()
>>> model.weight.grad[0, 2] = 0
>>> optim.step()
```

This way your 3rd channel on filter n°1 won't get updated by the backward pass and remain at `0`.

Comment: I understand now, thanks. I saw that backward hooking was also an option for exotic weights manipulation but I was hoping I wouldn't need to look into them and that there was any easy workaround. Thank you again for the answer!